# SQL SELECT from and EAV table

Tags: sql, database, attributes, sql-server-express, entity-attribute-value

Based on my previous questions I have this following tables:

```
  IrisColor 
  ID Description
   1 Blue 
   2 Gray 
   3 Green 
   4 Brown

 SkinColor 
  ID Description
   1 White 
   2 Asian 
   3 Dark       

Gender
  ID Description
   1 Male 
   2 Female
```

And the Attributes table

```
Attributes
  ID Description
   1 SkinColor 
   2 IrisColor 
   3 Gender
```

And also the EAV table:

```
PersonDetails
  PersonID AttributeID ValueID
   121       1            1
   121       2            2
   121       3            1
   122       1            2
   122       2            1
   122       3            1
```

So if I would want to select the Name, the attribute name and value for only the SkinColor I would do something like this:

```
SELECT p.Name,
       a.Description,
       v.Description
       FROM PersonDetails AS sd 
       INNER JOIN Subjects AS p ON sd.PersonID=p.ID 
       INNER JOIN SubjectAttributes AS a ON sd.AttributeID=a.ID
       INNER JOIN SkinColor AS v ON sd.ValueID= v.ID
```

But what should I do If I would want to select all the information for all of the persons from the database, not only skin color but iris color and gender too?

Previously I knew that from SkinColor I wanted to select that value, but in the PersonDetails I also have Values for IrisColor and Gender.

**INNER JOIN SkinColor AS v ON sd.ValueID= v.ID** this won't be appropriate anymore. How to replace this with something more dynamical?

Update:

I used this statement:

```
SELECT
    SubjectID,
    SkinColor,
    IrisColor,
    EyeLidFlisure,
    KnownEyeDeffect,
    Ethnicity,
    Height,
    DrivingLicense,
    Gender
FROM
(
SELECT SubjectID, attr.Description as attribute, ValueID from SubjectDetails, SubjectAttributes as attr WHERE SubjectDetails.AttributeID=attr.ID
) as t
PIVOT(MAX(ValueID) FOR attribute IN (SkinColor,IrisColor,Gender,EyeLidFlisure,KnownEyeDeffect,Ethnicity,Height,DrivingLicense)) AS t1
```

Now, I have all the attributes listed in separate columns, but instead of Value description I have Value ID. How should I continue?

Comment: Pivot EAV into regular table PersonDetailsT(PersonID,SkinColor,IrisColor , Gender ...) and join it to appropriate tables. Pivot is DBMS specific, tag DBMS properly.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about the joining part? because it's exactly my problem right now.

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: SQL Express + Microsoft sql server management studio

Comment: Why would you store the attributed in a separate table?  This seems like a strange implementation of an EAV model.  Normally the values go directly into the table?

Comment: So I don't store string values again and again and again, this way a map them with ints

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the complete solution (don't know if it is the easiest one.. but it works)

```
WITH Subject AS (

SELECT
    SubjectID,
    SkinColor,
    IrisColor,
    EyeLidFlisure,
    KnownEyeDeffect,
    Ethnicity,
    Height,
    DrivingLicense,
    Gender
FROM
(
SELECT SubjectID, attr.Description as attribute, ValueID from SubjectDetails, SubjectAttributes as attr WHERE SubjectDetails.AttributeID=attr.ID
) as t
PIVOT(MAX(ValueID) FOR attribute IN (SkinColor,IrisColor,Gender,EyeLidFlisure,KnownEyeDeffect,Ethnicity,Height,DrivingLicense)) AS t1
)

SELECT SubjectID,
whole.Name as Name,
whole.eMail as eMail,
skincolor.Description as SkinColor, 
iriscolor.Description as IrisColor,
eyelid.Description as EyeLidFlisure,
defect.Description as KnownEyeDeffect,
eth.Description as Ethnicity,
height.Description as Height,
dl.Description as DrivingLicense,
gender.Description as Gender

FROM Subject S
Left JOIN Subjects whole ON whole.ID=S.SubjectID
Left JOIN SkinColor skincolor ON S.SkinColor=skincolor.ID
Left JOIN IrisColor iriscolor ON S.IrisColor=iriscolor.ID
Left JOIN EyeLidFlisure eyelid ON S.EyeLidFlisure=eyelid.ID
Left JOIN KnownEyeDeffect defect ON S.KnownEyeDeffect=defect.ID
Left JOIN Ethnicity eth ON S.Ethnicity=eth.ID
Left JOIN Height height ON S.Height=height.ID
Left JOIN DrivingLicense dl ON S.DrivingLicense=dl.ID
Left JOIN Gender gender ON S.Gender=gender.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Guess you need dynamic sql built from attributes dictionary

```
declare @sql varchar(max)=
  'select PersonID , ' +
  +  stuff((select ','+Description + '.Description as ' + Description
             from Attributes
        for xml path ('')),1,1,'')
  + ' from (select PersonID, '
  +  stuff((select ',max(case AttributeID when ' + cast(ID as varchar(5)) +' then ValueID end) as ' + Description
        from Attributes
        for xml path ('')),1,1,'')
  +' from PersonDetails group by PersonID ) pvt' 
  +  (select ' left join ' + Description + ' on pvt.' + Description + ' = '+ Description + '.ID'
        from   Attributes
        for xml path (''));

exec (@sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data model is a bit arcane, because you have ids in the "person details" table that cannot have proper foreign key relationships.  You *could* put all the attributes in the same table.  Or have a separate table for each attribute.  Or -- as is common with EAV models -- put the descriptions directly into `PersonDetails`.

You are going to need to do something like this:

```
SELECT p.Name,
       sa.Description,
       ic.Description as IrisColor,
       g.Description as gender
FROM PersonDetails sd INNER JOIN
     Subjects p
     ON sd.PersonID = p.ID INNER JOIN
     SubjectAttributes sa
     ON sd.AttributeID = sa.ID 
     ON  LEFT JOIN
     SkinColor sc
     ON sd.ValueID = sc.ID AND sa.Description = 'SkinColor' LEFT JOIN
     IrisColor ic
     ON sd.ValueId = ic.ID AND sa.Description = 'IrisColor' LEFT JOIN
     Gender g
     ON sd.ValueId = g.ID AND sa.Description = 'Gender';
```